# 2 searchview on toolbar

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, searchview

Somehow I have a predefined searchview. When i implement a searchview trying to use Material Design I already have one and I'm left with 2 of them.

This is my main_layout which creates a searchview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="206dip"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="191dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"/>

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible" />

     </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Could you unpack your question a little and explain the issue with a few more words?

Comment: The thing is, when i inflate the menu and create the searchview i got an extra searchview. Becouse it seems the other one is created on the layout.

Comment: excellent, so maybe you can add that information to the question and someone wil answer. Also add "Android" to the title question so people can immediately see what technology you are asking about

Comment: (I'm not an expert on Android, so I can't help)